# Library platform keeps switching to 64-bit Windows in Delphi Seattle

Tags: delphi, ide, delphi-10-seattle

I have just installed Delphi Seattle Upgrade 1.

If I go to menu `Tools\Options\Environment options\Delphi options\Library` the *Selected platform* dropdown keeps reverting to 64-bit Windows.

[image]

After installing a lot of 3rd party packages with manual updates of the Library path, it is not funny to find out I put them all in the wrong place ;-(

I run Win32 code on a Win64 Windows 7. Only *once* did I build a 64-bit package, but it's been 32-bit ever since.

Anything I can/should do to fix this?

*Edited to add:*

- In the project manager, *all* projects in the project group show target platform Win32 only.
- In my source tree, *all* dproj files have `<Platform value="Win32">True</Platform>` and `<Platform value="Win64">False</Platform>` (5 out of 20 have an additional `<Platform value="OSX32">False</Platform>`)
- Explicitly saving the Default Layout does not help

Comment: I cannot reproduce this here.

Comment: @UweRaabe Do you mean that, when you freshly open your options, if you were previously viewing 32-bit library settings, it continues to show you 32-bit library settings first?

Comment: Yes, it opens with the last selected platform.

Comment: the same with PC of my colleges. i don't have such issue, but he has. we wasn't able to find out why it happens.

Comment: I've seen this too. Go ahead and report it at http://quality.embarcadero.com

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be that you are building a project configured for a 64-bit platform.

I tried the following :

- Set Library platform to 32-bit
- Build a project, Target : 64-bit

==> Library platform automatically updated to 64-bit

Check the configuration of your project (target platform), and also all the packages used during the building process. Maybe one is set to 64-bit causing this behavior.

Comment: The settings form always goes to the 64-bit settings by default.  The problem is getting to to show 32-bit settings when those were last viewed (or when currently using a 32-bit project).

Comment: I see a different behavior: Set 32-bit, create new package, add platform 64-bit, options still on 32-bit, compile 64-bit, options still on 32-bit.

Comment: Check the content of the .dproj file and find <Platforms>
                <Platform value="Win32">True</Platform>
                <Platform value="Win64">False</Platform>
            </Platforms> Delete this file, try again. Is the problem present on a new empty project ?

Comment: @UweRaabe That's odd.  Are you running under 32-bit windows?

Comment: @J..., Win8.1 x64 Delphi 10 Seattle Update 1 with all available Hotfixes.

Comment: A possible solution would be to have the same paths for both x64 and x86 BUT make use of the $(Platform) variable in each added path. You may need to rearrange your files. $(Platform) = Win64 when target is 64-bit, $(Platform) = Win32 when target is 32-bit. For example have your paths like C:\MyLib\$(Plateform) and put your file in C:\MyLib\Win64 and C:\MyLib\Win32.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing you can do about this. This caught me out a couple of times too. It doesn't seem to be a preference stored anywhere (or contextual based on the current project settings). The form just defaults to showing you the 64-bit Library settings when it is first opened.

The only way to fix this is to remove the mistakenly added entries from the 64-bit library and move them to the 32-bit library.  If there are really a lot, you can always script this or do it in the registry rather than via the IDE's GUI.